# Netlogo set xcor and ycor in a interval

Tags: random, coordinates, netlogo, intervals

I would like to set up the xcor and ycor using a random number inside a precise interval.
In particular, I would like my turtles to be spread out in the first half of the world and then make them move to the other half if certain conditions are satisfied.
So I was thinking that I could set xcor and ycor by letting netlogo choose a random number in the interval [0-16] which should coincide with the first half of my world. How can I do it ?

I was thinking something like

```
setxy random-integer [0-16]
```

but it clearly does not work. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons, why it isn't working.

1. `setxy` expects two inputs, one for the x and one for the y coordinate. (See [setxy entrance](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#setxy) in the netlogo-dictionary)
2. The reporter, that returns random integers is simply `random` and returns values stricly less than the given (positive) number. (See [random entrance](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random) in the netlogo-dictionary)

The solution for your problem is:

```
setxy random 17 random 17
```

assuming that the world is rectangular.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I ended up doing the following
 setxy random 32 random 16, in that way turtles will spread along all the x axis and the positive values of y axe. So they now spread on the upper half of my world.